# map Ubuntu Linux folders in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu machine and a certain folder structure there. I'd like that folder structure to be accessible for read/write from my Mac OSX box.

Do I need to install and configure Samba? or something else perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samba is one option. Finder additionally supports FTP and AFP shares.

It seems you want Finder integration? Using 3rd party software (e.g. the "Transmit Disk" feature of [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/), or [FUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) (SSHFS?) opens up more options for that.